# HTML to JAVASCRIPT conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, href

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (window!= top)
    <a href="#" target="_parent">Go to Top Window</a>;
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the above code to work but "a href" (HTML) does not work in javascript. Can anyone spread some insight on how I can make this url be a part of the javascript? And I do need to use href because of that target attribute and the "#". This seems impossible.. but please let me know if you have any ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here...

Comment: What should the JavaScript do to the link? Change the href? the target? Navigate to it? Hide it? Please clarify.

Comment: The JavaScript is supposed to show the link if it is in a frameset, and NOT show the link if it is NOT in a frameset.

Answer (score 1):

Not a clear question but you need something like,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (window!= top)
    document.write('<a href="#" target="_parent">Go to Top Window</a>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment you added, I think you're looking for

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (window != top) {
    document.write('<a href="#" target="_top">Go to Top Window</a>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Google" break out of frames.  here's a link for javascript:  http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/framebreak.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In your document, give that anchor a unique id `<a id="hideThisAnchorWhenNotInAFrameset" href="#" target="_parent">Go to Top Window</a>`, then in your JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var thatAnchorTag = document.getElementById('hideThisAnchorWhenNotInAFrameset');
    function logicSaysItsAFrameset() {
        return (window != top); //Not really sure if this is the best method.
    }
    if (logicSaysItsAFrameset()) {
        thatAnchorTag.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        thatAnchorTag.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```